# How to integrate IP Camera into Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, textures, webcam

I'm trying to map remote web camera view into a Unity 3D gameObject.
I want to map network IP Camera as a webcam texture on my gameObject (Plane).
Once I have tried to map my local camera webcam texture, It is working.
Is there a way to map a remote one?
At least can I insert remote video over the internet? like a youtube video?
If it is possible, then IP camera should not be a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [VideoPlayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html) class introduced in Unity 5.6:

> Content can be either a VideoClip imported asset or a URL such as
>   file:// or http://.

The [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoPlayer.html) explicitly mentions network streaming.

> Unity’s video features include the hardware-accelerated and software
>   decoding of Video files, transparency support, multiple audio tracks,
>   and **network streaming**.